# RNN: Get prediction from a text input after the model is trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, text-classification

I am new to RNNs and I have been working on a small binary label classifier. I have been able to get a stable model with satisfactory results.

However, I am having a hard time using the model to classify new inputs and I was wondering if any of you could help me. Please see my code below for reference.

Thank you very much.

```
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input, 
Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence, text
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from matplotlib import pyplot

class tensor_rnn():
def __init__(self, hidden_layers=3):
    self.data_path = 'C:\\\\Users\\cmazz\\PycharmProjects\\InvestmentAnalysis_2.0\\Sentiment\\Finance_Articles\\'
    # self.corp_paths = corpora_paths
    self.h_layers = hidden_layers
    self.num_words = []
    good = pd.read_csv(self.data_path + 'GoodO.csv')
    good['Polarity'] = 'pos'
    for line in good['Head'].tolist():
        counter = len(line.split())
        self.num_words.append(counter)
    bad = pd.read_csv(self.data_path + 'BadO.csv')
    bad['Polarity'] = 'neg'
    for line in bad['Head'].tolist():
        counter = len(line.split())
        self.num_words.append(counter)
    self.features = pd.concat([good, bad]).reset_index(drop=True)
    self.features = shuffle(self.features)

    self.max_len = len(max(self.features['Head'].tolist()))
    # self.train, self.test = train_test_split(features, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
    X = self.features['Head']
    Y = self.features['Polarity']
    le = LabelEncoder()
    Y = le.fit_transform(Y)
    Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
    self.X_train, self.X_test, self.Y_train, self.Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30)
    self.tok = preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=len(self.num_words))
    self.tok.fit_on_texts(self.X_train)
    sequences = self.tok.texts_to_sequences(self.X_train)
    self.sequences_matrix = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=self.max_len)

def RNN(self):
    inputs = Input(name='inputs', shape=[self.max_len])
    layer = Embedding(len(self.num_words), 30, input_length=self.max_len)(inputs)
    # layer = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(layer)
    layer = LSTM(32)(layer)
    layer = Dense(256, name='FC1')(layer)
    layer = Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(1, name='out_layer')(layer)
    layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layer)
    return model

def model_train(self):
    self.model = self.RNN()
    self.model.summary()
    self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])   # RMSprop()

def model_test(self):
    self.history = self.model.fit(self.sequences_matrix, self.Y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=3,
              validation_split=0.30, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001)])
    test_sequences = self.tok.texts_to_sequences(self.X_test)
    test_sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(test_sequences, maxlen=self.max_len)
    accr = self.model.evaluate(test_sequences_matrix, self.Y_test)
    print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0], accr[1]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = tensor_rnn()
    a.model_train()
    a.model_test()
    a.model.save('C:\\\\Users\\cmazz\\PycharmProjects\\'
                              'InvestmentAnalysis_2.0\\RNN_Model.h5', 
    include_optimizer=True)
     b = models.load_model('C:\\\\Users\\cmazz\\PycharmProjects\\'
                              'InvestmentAnalysis_2.0\\RNN_Model.h5')
    stringy = ['Fund managers back away from Amazon as they cut FANG exposure']
    prediction = b.predict(np.array(stringy))
    print(prediction)
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected inputs to have shape
>   (39,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); specify where exactly the error occurs, and think if, say, all these `pyplot` lines are necessary in order to *understand your issue* (hint: they are not)...

Comment: You are absolutely right, however these are used in the code to test the accuracy of the models and to look for overfiting. I non the less remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the ValueError and `prediction = b.predict(np.array(stringy))`, I think you need to tokenize your input string.

Comment: Hi Michael, if I tokenize the string I get the following error:
stringy = text.Tokenizer(len(stringy))
    prediction = b.predict(stringy)
    print(prediction)
AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: Hello Claudio, it looks like you are tokenizing the length of the string, rather than the string itself. 

Does https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.1-using-word-embeddings.ipynb help?

Comment: I tried passing the Tokenizer both the list containing the string as well as passing the string itself but both did not work when I tried getting predictions out of it.

Comment: Does the shape of the string match what the tokenizer is expecting? Sometimes when putting in a single instance, one forgets to make sure it is shaped correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved this by following your advice and padding the sentence with single character strings to match the expected shape.